# How can we get Cascading Lookup Columns in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

How to get the cascaded Lookup columns in sharepoint 2010,Iam having requirement 
like i have two lists(Category List and Sub category list)..For each item in category 
list i have 5 different items in sub category list..

So if i select one item(ex:Desktop) in Category list,the next column dropdown has to come 
corresponding items of sub category list which relates to item(Desktop) in category list..

Iam using three lists here 1)Category
               2)Sub Category
               3)Ticket
calling category and sub category title columns as lookup columns in Ticket List..

i have searched some sites like http://www.sharepointboris.net/js/spcd/ but didnt find the solution

Could anyone help me achieve this?

Thanks,
Naresh.

Comment: Thanks for commenting that you have found the answer, but it would be better if you could post an answer containing a little more detail on how you solved the problem, with the link added for reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I got the Solution from http://cascadefilterlookup.codeplex.com

Comment: can you add details for the reason you chose this option over others?

Answer (score 2):

Its can also be done in InfoPath, I highly recommend SPservices though.
Examples:

- [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharatgupta/archive/2013/03/07/create-cascading-dropdown-in-browser-enabled-infopath-form-using-infopath-2010.aspx)
- [PointBeyond](http://www.pointbeyond.com/2011/11/20/cascading-dropdowns-in-infopath-2010/)

Comment: thanks for your answer...but i got solution from this link http://cascadefilterlookup.codeplex.com

Comment: @naresh if this codeplex module helped you, you should add it as answer and mark it as answer as soon as you can

Comment: can you give me some resource to get this done in InfoPath?

Comment: Updated answer with links to examples

Answer (score 2):

I've used a [custom field](http://cascddlistwithfilter.codeplex.com/) for this request in SP 2007. I don't know for sure if you can use it in SP 2010.

Comment: thanks for your answer...but i got solution from this link     http://cascadefilterlookup.codeplex.com

Comment: the questions was about cascaded lookup fields. the link you have provided is about cascaded dropdown list so it makes a copy of the text and actually does not provide a real lookup

Comment: of course I was speaking about the Naresh link and not the one provided by Sven Gillis

Answer (score 1):

Check out SPServices Jquery library which provides cascading dropdown functionality among many others: http://spservices.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: thanks for your answer...but i got solution from this link http://cascadefilterlookup.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

InfoPath is probably the easier solution to implement.

Comment: thanks for your answer...but i got solution from this link http://cascadefilterlookup.codeplex.com

Comment: @david : can you give me some resources to get this done in InfoPath?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the Metadata, I suggest you the best way to do the Category-Subcategory-Item senario at [here](http://www.cmswire.com/cms/document-management/sharepoint-2010-using-taxonomy-metadata-to-improve-navigation-browsing-007380.php).

Comment: thanks for your answer...but i got solution from this link http://cascadefilterlookup.codeplex.com

Comment: That tool looks good!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share the link which would guide you in creating the cascading dropdowns in SharePoint
[Cascading or Filtered dropdowns in LookUp Columns](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2012/02/cascading-dropdown-or-filtered-values.html)
Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

This is other custom field [SharePoint Cascaded Lookup](http://www.sharepointadd-ons.com/sharepoint-cascaded-site-lookup)