# Relational Lists Help

Tags: list

I am wondering whether it is possible to do the following. I am working on a simple CRM system using lists.

I have a contact lists with company name.
I have an opportunites list. When a user selects a company name I want the contact list lookup to be filtered so its only relevant to the company selected.

Is it possible to do this ? Appreciate any help here.

Thanks

Comment: This may help: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25535/how-can-we-get-cascading-lookup-columns-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: or Search for cascading lookup column in google.